# Why is Airflow 1.10.12 much slower than 1.10.10?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Recently I have my airflow upgraded from 1.10.10 to 1.10.12 and find my dags are scheduled much slower than before. One of my dag is as follows and it has 400 Tasks of DummyOperator. It took only 4+mins with 1.10.10 while it took more than 16mins with 1.10.12.

Can someone tell me what the problem may be？I tried to compare the code diff between these two versions with https://github.com/apache/airflow/compare/1.10.10...1.10.12 and failed to draw a conclusion.

[image]

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import datetime
import os
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
default_args = {
    "owner": "doow",
    "start_date": datetime.strptime("2020-11-23 18:06:42", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
}
dag = DAG(
    default_args=default_args,
    params={"today": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")},
    dag_id="huge_dag_demo",
    schedule_interval=None,
)
task_0 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_0",
    dag=dag,
)

task_1 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_1",
    dag=dag,
)

task_2 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_2",
    dag=dag,
)

task_3 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_3",
    dag=dag,
)

task_4 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_4",
    dag=dag,
)

task_5 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_5",
    dag=dag,
)

task_6 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_6",
    dag=dag,
)

task_7 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_7",
    dag=dag,
)

task_8 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_8",
    dag=dag,
)

task_9 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_9",
    dag=dag,
)

task_10 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_10",
    dag=dag,
)

task_11 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_11",
    dag=dag,
)

task_12 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_12",
    dag=dag,
)

task_13 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_13",
    dag=dag,
)

task_14 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_14",
    dag=dag,
)

task_15 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_15",
    dag=dag,
)

task_16 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_16",
    dag=dag,
)

task_17 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_17",
    dag=dag,
)

task_18 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_18",
    dag=dag,
)

task_19 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_19",
    dag=dag,
)

task_20 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_20",
    dag=dag,
)

task_21 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_21",
    dag=dag,
)

task_22 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_22",
    dag=dag,
)

task_23 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_23",
    dag=dag,
)

task_24 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_24",
    dag=dag,
)

task_25 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_25",
    dag=dag,
)

task_26 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_26",
    dag=dag,
)

task_27 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_27",
    dag=dag,
)

task_28 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_28",
    dag=dag,
)

task_29 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_29",
    dag=dag,
)

task_30 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_30",
    dag=dag,
)

task_31 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_31",
    dag=dag,
)

task_32 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_32",
    dag=dag,
)

task_33 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_33",
    dag=dag,
)

task_34 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_34",
    dag=dag,
)

task_35 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_35",
    dag=dag,
)

task_36 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_36",
    dag=dag,
)

task_37 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_37",
    dag=dag,
)

task_38 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_38",
    dag=dag,
)

task_39 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_39",
    dag=dag,
)

task_40 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_40",
    dag=dag,
)

task_41 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_41",
    dag=dag,
)

task_42 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_42",
    dag=dag,
)

task_43 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_43",
    dag=dag,
)

task_44 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_44",
    dag=dag,
)

task_45 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_45",
    dag=dag,
)

task_46 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_46",
    dag=dag,
)

task_47 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_47",
    dag=dag,
)

task_48 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_48",
    dag=dag,
)

task_49 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_49",
    dag=dag,
)

task_50 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_50",
    dag=dag,
)

task_51 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_51",
    dag=dag,
)

task_52 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_52",
    dag=dag,
)

task_53 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_53",
    dag=dag,
)

task_54 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_54",
    dag=dag,
)

task_55 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_55",
    dag=dag,
)

task_56 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_56",
    dag=dag,
)

task_57 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_57",
    dag=dag,
)

task_58 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_58",
    dag=dag,
)

task_59 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_59",
    dag=dag,
)

task_60 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_60",
    dag=dag,
)

task_61 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_61",
    dag=dag,
)

task_62 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_62",
    dag=dag,
)

task_63 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_63",
    dag=dag,
)

task_64 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_64",
    dag=dag,
)

task_65 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_65",
    dag=dag,
)

task_66 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_66",
    dag=dag,
)

task_67 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_67",
    dag=dag,
)

task_68 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_68",
    dag=dag,
)

task_69 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_69",
    dag=dag,
)

task_70 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_70",
    dag=dag,
)

task_71 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_71",
    dag=dag,
)

task_72 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_72",
    dag=dag,
)

task_73 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_73",
    dag=dag,
)

task_74 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_74",
    dag=dag,
)

task_75 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_75",
    dag=dag,
)

task_76 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_76",
    dag=dag,
)

task_77 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_77",
    dag=dag,
)

task_78 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_78",
    dag=dag,
)

task_79 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_79",
    dag=dag,
)

task_80 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_80",
    dag=dag,
)

task_81 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_81",
    dag=dag,
)

task_82 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_82",
    dag=dag,
)

task_83 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_83",
    dag=dag,
)

task_84 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_84",
    dag=dag,
)

task_85 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_85",
    dag=dag,
)

task_86 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_86",
    dag=dag,
)

task_87 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_87",
    dag=dag,
)

task_88 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_88",
    dag=dag,
)

task_89 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_89",
    dag=dag,
)

task_90 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_90",
    dag=dag,
)

task_91 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_91",
    dag=dag,
)

task_92 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_92",
    dag=dag,
)

task_93 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_93",
    dag=dag,
)

task_94 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_94",
    dag=dag,
)

task_95 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_95",
    dag=dag,
)

task_96 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_96",
    dag=dag,
)

task_97 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_97",
    dag=dag,
)

task_98 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_98",
    dag=dag,
)

task_99 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_99",
    dag=dag,
)

task_100 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_100",
    dag=dag,
)

task_101 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_101",
    dag=dag,
)

task_102 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_102",
    dag=dag,
)

task_103 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_103",
    dag=dag,
)

task_104 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_104",
    dag=dag,
)

task_105 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_105",
    dag=dag,
)

task_106 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_106",
    dag=dag,
)

task_107 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_107",
    dag=dag,
)

task_108 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_108",
    dag=dag,
)

task_109 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_109",
    dag=dag,
)

task_110 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="task_110",
    dag=dag,
)
# more here, 400 tasks totally...

task_1 << task_0
task_2 << task_0
task_2 << task_1
task_3 << task_0
task_3 << task_1
task_3 << task_2
task_4 << task_1
task_4 << task_2
task_4 << task_3
task_5 << task_2
task_5 << task_3
task_5 << task_4
task_6 << task_0
task_6 << task_1
task_6 << task_3
task_6 << task_4
task_6 << task_5
task_7 << task_1
task_7 << task_2
task_7 << task_3
task_7 << task_4
task_7 << task_5
task_8 << task_0
task_8 << task_2
task_8 << task_3
task_8 << task_6
task_8 << task_7
task_9 << task_1
task_9 << task_2
task_9 << task_3
task_9 << task_5
task_9 << task_6
task_9 << task_7
task_9 << task_8
task_10 << task_1
task_10 << task_2
task_10 << task_5
task_10 << task_8
task_10 << task_9
task_11 << task_0
task_11 << task_1
task_11 << task_3
task_11 << task_4
task_11 << task_5
task_11 << task_8
task_11 << task_10
task_12 << task_0
task_12 << task_1
task_12 << task_3
task_12 << task_6
task_12 << task_7
task_12 << task_8
task_12 << task_9
task_13 << task_1
task_13 << task_2
task_13 << task_5
task_13 << task_6
task_13 << task_10
task_13 << task_11
task_14 << task_1
task_14 << task_4
task_14 << task_6
task_14 << task_10
task_14 << task_11
task_14 << task_12
task_15 << task_2
task_15 << task_3
task_15 << task_4
task_15 << task_6
task_15 << task_7
task_15 << task_9
task_15 << task_10
task_15 << task_13
task_16 << task_0
task_16 << task_4
task_16 << task_8
task_16 << task_10
task_16 << task_11
task_16 << task_12
task_16 << task_14
task_17 << task_1
task_17 << task_5
task_17 << task_6
task_17 << task_11
task_17 << task_12
task_17 << task_14
task_17 << task_16
task_18 << task_0
task_18 << task_2
task_18 << task_3
task_18 << task_6
task_18 << task_11
task_18 << task_12
task_18 << task_14
task_18 << task_17
task_19 << task_7
task_19 << task_8
task_19 << task_11
task_19 << task_12
task_19 << task_14
task_19 << task_15
task_19 << task_16
task_19 << task_17
task_20 << task_0
task_20 << task_3
task_20 << task_8
task_20 << task_9
task_20 << task_11
task_20 << task_13
task_20 << task_15
task_20 << task_18
task_21 << task_0
task_21 << task_4
task_21 << task_5
task_21 << task_8
task_21 << task_11
task_21 << task_13
task_21 << task_18
task_21 << task_19
task_21 << task_20
task_22 << task_4
task_22 << task_8
task_22 << task_11
task_22 << task_13
task_22 << task_14
task_22 << task_16
task_22 << task_19
task_22 << task_21
task_23 << task_0
task_23 << task_9
task_23 << task_10
task_23 << task_13
task_23 << task_14
task_23 << task_20
task_23 << task_21
task_24 << task_3
task_24 << task_5
task_24 << task_11
task_24 << task_12
task_24 << task_14
task_24 << task_15
task_24 << task_18
task_24 << task_22
task_25 << task_3
task_25 << task_4
task_25 << task_12
task_25 << task_16
task_25 << task_18
task_25 << task_19
task_25 << task_21
task_25 << task_24
task_26 << task_2
task_26 << task_8
task_26 << task_10
task_26 << task_11
task_26 << task_13
task_26 << task_14
task_26 << task_18
task_26 << task_22
task_27 << task_2
task_27 << task_7
task_27 << task_10
task_27 << task_11
task_27 << task_13
task_27 << task_18
task_27 << task_20
task_27 << task_22
task_27 << task_24
task_28 << task_1
task_28 << task_10
task_28 << task_13
task_28 << task_18
task_28 << task_22
task_28 << task_23
task_28 << task_25
task_28 << task_26
task_29 << task_2
task_29 << task_3
task_29 << task_4
task_29 << task_6
task_29 << task_7
task_29 << task_13
task_29 << task_22
task_29 << task_23
task_29 << task_28
task_30 << task_5
task_30 << task_13
task_30 << task_15
task_30 << task_18
task_30 << task_21
task_30 << task_26
task_30 << task_29
task_31 << task_1
task_31 << task_4
task_31 << task_13
task_31 << task_16
task_31 << task_17
task_31 << task_18
task_31 << task_28
task_32 << task_2
task_32 << task_4
task_32 << task_7
task_32 << task_9
task_32 << task_12
task_32 << task_14
task_32 << task_15
task_32 << task_18
task_32 << task_24
task_33 << task_14
task_33 << task_16
task_33 << task_20
task_33 << task_21
task_33 << task_22
task_33 << task_24
task_33 << task_26
task_33 << task_28
task_33 << task_31
task_34 << task_7
task_34 << task_10
task_34 << task_14
task_34 << task_20
task_34 << task_22
task_34 << task_23
task_34 << task_24
task_34 << task_26
task_35 << task_4
task_35 << task_8
task_35 << task_12
task_35 << task_15
task_35 << task_19
task_35 << task_21
task_35 << task_22
task_35 << task_28
task_36 << task_1
task_36 << task_34
task_36 << task_3
task_36 << task_11
task_36 << task_12
task_36 << task_15
task_36 << task_17
task_37 << task_0
task_37 << task_3
task_37 << task_4
task_37 << task_7
task_37 << task_16
task_37 << task_17
task_37 << task_19
task_37 << task_21
task_37 << task_23
task_38 << task_2
task_38 << task_36
task_38 << task_4
task_38 << task_15
task_38 << task_16
task_38 << task_17
task_38 << task_22
task_38 << task_23
task_38 << task_28
task_39 << task_2
task_39 << task_34
task_39 << task_10
task_39 << task_19
task_39 << task_23
task_39 << task_25
task_39 << task_26
task_39 << task_31
task_40 << task_35
task_40 << task_3
task_40 << task_37
task_40 << task_12
task_40 << task_23
task_40 << task_25
task_40 << task_29
task_41 << task_0
task_41 << task_3
task_41 << task_36
task_41 << task_37
task_41 << task_6
task_41 << task_39
task_41 << task_40
task_41 << task_11
task_41 << task_14
task_41 << task_27
task_42 << task_34
task_42 << task_3
task_42 << task_36
task_42 << task_11
task_42 << task_14
task_42 << task_19
task_42 << task_24
task_42 << task_28
task_42 << task_30
task_42 << task_31
task_43 << task_34
task_43 << task_3
task_43 << task_2
task_43 << task_37
task_43 << task_9
task_43 << task_14
task_43 << task_15
task_43 << task_19
task_43 << task_23
task_43 << task_29
task_44 << task_34
task_44 << task_37
task_44 << task_38
task_44 << task_6
task_44 << task_40
task_44 << task_11
task_44 << task_12
task_44 << task_24
task_44 << task_27
task_45 << task_2
task_45 << task_4
task_45 << task_5
task_45 << task_7
task_45 << task_9
task_45 << task_44
task_45 << task_15
task_45 << task_20
task_45 << task_26
task_45 << task_29
task_46 << task_32
task_46 << task_2
task_46 << task_38
task_46 << task_41
task_46 << task_43
task_46 << task_12
task_46 << task_16
task_46 << task_20
task_46 << task_21
task_47 << task_33
task_47 << task_12
task_47 << task_15
task_47 << task_17
task_47 << task_18
task_47 << task_23
task_47 << task_26
task_48 << task_8
task_48 << task_45
task_48 << task_15
task_48 << task_18
task_48 << task_20
task_48 << task_23
task_48 << task_25
task_48 << task_30
task_49 << task_32
task_49 << task_48
task_49 << task_18
task_49 << task_20
task_49 << task_23
task_49 << task_25
task_49 << task_27
task_49 << task_30
task_49 << task_31
task_50 << task_2
task_50 << task_38
task_50 << task_10
task_50 << task_13
task_50 << task_15
task_50 << task_16
task_50 << task_17
task_50 << task_19
task_50 << task_26
task_51 << task_0
task_51 << task_35
task_51 << task_3
task_51 << task_37
task_51 << task_5
task_51 << task_42
task_51 << task_43
task_51 << task_15
task_51 << task_25
task_51 << task_27
task_52 << task_38
task_52 << task_39
task_52 << task_12
task_52 << task_15
task_52 << task_51
task_52 << task_22
task_52 << task_24
task_52 << task_28
task_52 << task_30
task_53 << task_0
task_53 << task_2
task_53 << task_36
task_53 << task_38
task_53 << task_11
task_53 << task_12
task_53 << task_45
task_53 << task_50
task_54 << task_36
task_54 << task_5
task_54 << task_41
task_54 << task_11
task_54 << task_45
task_54 << task_49
task_54 << task_18
task_54 << task_20
task_54 << task_23
task_55 << task_0
task_55 << task_10
task_55 << task_42
task_55 << task_46
task_55 << task_16
task_55 << task_17
task_55 << task_23
task_56 << task_7
task_56 << task_10
task_56 << task_15
task_56 << task_18
task_56 << task_50
task_56 << task_52
task_56 << task_21
task_56 << task_22
task_56 << task_29
task_57 << task_33
task_57 << task_35
task_57 << task_37
task_57 << task_39
task_57 << task_11
task_57 << task_43
task_57 << task_13
task_57 << task_51
task_57 << task_28
task_57 << task_30
task_58 << task_0
task_58 << task_35
task_58 << task_5
task_58 << task_8
task_58 << task_48
task_58 << task_50
task_58 << task_21
task_58 << task_55
task_58 << task_27
task_58 << task_29
task_59 << task_0
task_59 << task_34
task_59 << task_3
task_59 << task_37
task_59 << task_40
task_59 << task_11
task_59 << task_48
task_59 << task_18
task_59 << task_25
task_59 << task_28
task_60 << task_10
task_60 << task_11
task_60 << task_12
task_60 << task_21
task_60 << task_22
task_60 << task_23
task_60 << task_25
task_60 << task_58
task_60 << task_28
task_61 << task_37
task_61 << task_6
task_61 << task_8
task_61 << task_11
task_61 << task_12
task_61 << task_15
task_61 << task_50
task_61 << task_53
task_61 << task_25
task_61 << task_26
task_62 << task_10
task_62 << task_12
task_62 << task_13
task_62 << task_14
task_62 << task_53
task_62 << task_56
task_62 << task_26
task_63 << task_36
task_63 << task_37
task_63 << task_47
task_63 << task_15
task_63 << task_20
task_63 << task_25
task_63 << task_26
task_63 << task_61
task_64 << task_3
task_64 << task_36
task_64 << task_12
task_64 << task_46
task_64 << task_17
task_64 << task_18
task_64 << task_19
task_64 << task_52
task_64 << task_60
task_65 << task_33
task_65 << task_34
task_65 << task_35
task_65 << task_39
task_65 << task_43
task_65 << task_14
task_65 << task_16
task_65 << task_55
task_65 << task_28
task_65 << task_63
task_66 << task_32
task_66 << task_64
task_66 << task_34
task_66 << task_37
task_66 << task_40
task_66 << task_48
task_66 << task_54
task_66 << task_22
task_66 << task_56
task_66 << task_61
task_67 << task_64
task_67 << task_37
task_67 << task_38
task_67 << task_7
task_67 << task_12
task_67 << task_46
task_67 << task_15
task_67 << task_48
task_67 << task_57
task_67 << task_63
task_68 << task_64
task_68 << task_38
task_68 << task_12
task_68 << task_47
task_68 << task_16
task_68 << task_19
task_68 << task_25
task_68 << task_27
task_68 << task_60
task_68 << task_63
task_69 << task_64
task_69 << task_1
task_69 << task_38
task_69 << task_6
task_69 << task_52
task_69 << task_55
task_69 << task_23
task_69 << task_31
task_70 << task_32
task_70 << task_33
task_70 << task_64
task_70 << task_5
task_70 << task_6
task_70 << task_7
task_70 << task_52
task_70 << task_54
task_70 << task_60
task_71 << task_0
task_71 << task_34
task_71 << task_35
task_71 << task_41
task_71 << task_10
task_71 << task_16
task_71 << task_48
task_71 << task_19
task_71 << task_53
task_71 << task_30
task_72 << task_0
task_72 << task_2
task_72 << task_35
task_72 << task_36
task_72 << task_21
task_72 << task_26
task_72 << task_62
task_73 << task_4
task_73 << task_71
task_73 << task_7
task_73 << task_10
task_73 << task_11
task_73 << task_43
task_73 << task_44
task_73 << task_62
task_73 << task_28
task_73 << task_30
task_74 << task_8
task_74 << task_41
task_74 << task_15
task_74 << task_17
task_74 << task_52
task_74 << task_22
task_74 << task_27
task_74 << task_31
task_75 << task_34
task_75 << task_67
task_75 << task_39
task_75 << task_40
task_75 << task_11
task_75 << task_18
task_75 << task_53
task_75 << task_55
task_75 << task_59
task_75 << task_31
task_76 << task_64
task_76 << task_67
task_76 << task_41
task_76 << task_51
task_76 << task_52
task_76 << task_19
task_76 << task_23
task_76 << task_59
task_76 << task_31
task_77 << task_2
task_77 << task_35
task_77 << task_36
task_77 << task_37
task_77 << task_39
task_77 << task_44
task_77 << task_13
task_77 << task_50
task_77 << task_59
task_77 << task_61
task_78 << task_3
task_78 << task_6
task_78 << task_42
task_78 << task_11
task_78 << task_12
task_78 << task_13
task_78 << task_22
task_78 << task_26
task_78 << task_31
task_78 << task_63
task_79 << task_34
task_79 << task_5
task_79 << task_69
task_79 << task_8
task_79 << task_56
task_79 << task_25
task_79 << task_26
task_79 << task_59
task_80 << task_32
task_80 << task_6
task_80 << task_74
task_80 << task_75
task_80 << task_12
task_80 << task_50
task_80 << task_53
task_80 << task_58
task_80 << task_27
task_81 << task_1
task_81 << task_70
task_81 << task_7
task_81 << task_39
task_81 << task_41
task_81 << task_43
task_81 << task_11
task_81 << task_16
task_81 << task_19
task_82 << task_36
task_82 << task_8
task_82 << task_74
task_82 << task_43
task_82 << task_45
task_82 << task_54
task_82 << task_30
task_82 << task_63
task_83 << task_33
task_83 << task_35
task_83 << task_40
task_83 << task_15
task_83 << task_18
task_83 << task_20
task_83 << task_21
task_83 << task_58
task_83 << task_60
task_83 << task_63
task_84 << task_32
task_84 << task_1
task_84 << task_3
task_84 << task_68
task_84 << task_7
task_84 << task_77
task_84 << task_80
task_84 << task_49
task_84 << task_19
task_84 << task_28
task_85 << task_32
task_85 << task_74
task_85 << task_12
task_85 << task_13
task_85 << task_14
task_85 << task_81
task_85 << task_51
task_85 << task_24
task_85 << task_58
task_85 << task_31
task_86 << task_0
task_86 << task_1
task_86 << task_65
task_86 << task_2
task_86 << task_38
task_86 << task_41
task_86 << task_77
task_86 << task_50
task_86 << task_57
task_86 << task_31
task_87 << task_32
task_87 << task_2
task_87 << task_36
task_87 << task_4
task_87 << task_38
task_87 << task_71
task_87 << task_82
task_87 << task_86
task_87 << task_24
task_87 << task_63
task_88 << task_69
task_88 << task_43
task_88 << task_77
task_88 << task_15
task_88 << task_49
task_88 << task_50
task_88 << task_19
task_88 << task_20
task_88 << task_56
task_88 << task_28
task_89 << task_3
task_89 << task_69
task_89 << task_42
task_89 << task_11
task_89 << task_45
task_89 << task_46
task_89 << task_48
task_89 << task_49
task_89 << task_52
task_89 << task_60
task_90 << task_0
task_90 << task_71
task_90 << task_7
task_90 << task_41
task_90 << task_43
task_90 << task_53
task_90 << task_86
task_90 << task_25
task_90 << task_60
task_91 << task_65
task_91 << task_2
task_91 << task_1
task_91 << task_69
task_91 << task_40
task_91 << task_10
task_91 << task_74
task_91 << task_76
task_91 << task_28
task_91 << task_29
task_92 << task_5
task_92 << task_10
task_92 << task_44
task_92 << task_46
task_92 << task_78
task_92 << task_49
task_92 << task_82
task_92 << task_85
task_92 << task_86
task_92 << task_23
task_93 << task_68
task_93 << task_37
task_93 << task_5
task_93 << task_73
task_93 << task_15
task_93 << task_48
task_93 << task_50
task_93 << task_51
task_93 << task_84
task_93 << task_85
task_94 << task_66
task_94 << task_69
task_94 << task_43
task_94 << task_45
task_94 << task_78
task_94 << task_55
task_94 << task_26
task_94 << task_92
task_94 << task_30
task_95 << task_66
task_95 << task_10
task_95 << task_16
task_95 << task_51
task_95 << task_84
task_95 << task_22
task_95 << task_25
task_95 << task_26
task_95 << task_60
task_95 << task_31
task_96 << task_35
task_96 << task_5
task_96 << task_6
task_96 << task_74
task_96 << task_12
task_96 << task_81
task_96 << task_20
task_96 << task_24
task_96 << task_89
task_96 << task_90
task_97 << task_6
task_97 << task_8
task_97 << task_17
task_97 << task_86
task_97 << task_55
task_97 << task_87
task_97 << task_61
task_97 << task_31
task_98 << task_37
task_98 << task_69
task_98 << task_71
task_98 << task_73
task_98 << task_41
task_98 << task_76
task_98 << task_15
task_98 << task_19
task_98 << task_83
task_98 << task_55
task_99 << task_98
task_99 << task_9
task_99 << task_45
task_99 << task_47
task_99 << task_48
task_99 << task_49
#more here...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/11780

[The fix](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/11010) has already been merged for 1.10.13 which should be released tomorrow. In the meantime you can test it 1.10.13rc using the following:

```
pip install 'apache-airflow==1.10.13rc1'
```

Comment: Thanks! 1.10.13 works and performs even better than 1.10.10

Comment: @doowhtron If the answer helped, you should upvote and accept it (: